# AWS S3 redirection rules based on user agent

Tags: amazon-s3

Is it possible to configure S3 static website using redirection rules in a way that based on the user agent different web pages are served?

One easy way to do is have node server/ nginx server in between. Any other options?

Answer (score 2):

No, the Amazon S3 in-built redirection capabilities for Static Website Hosting **does not have the ability to redirect based on rules**. It simply redirects a request for one URL to another URL.

See: [Configuring a Web Page Redirect](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html)

Your application would need to **detect the User Agent** and could then refer to content in Amazon S3 based upon the agent value. For example, you could have different paths within a bucket, and redirect users to the appropriate path based upon their agent.